# pandas: split string, and count values?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas dataset with a column that's a comma-separated string, e.g. `1,2,3,10`:

```
data = [
  { 'id': 1, 'score': 9, 'topics': '11,22,30' },
  { 'id': 2, 'score': 7, 'topics': '11,18,30' },
  { 'id': 3, 'score': 6, 'topics': '1,12,30' },
  { 'id': 4, 'score': 4, 'topics': '1,18,30' }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I'd like to get a count and a mean score for each value in `topics`. So:

```
topic_id,count,mean
1,2,5
11,2,8
12,1,6
```

et cetera. How can I do this?

I've got as far as:

```
df['topic_ids'] = df.topics.str.split()
```

But now I guess I want to explode `topic_ids` out, so there's a column for each unique value in the entire set of values...?

Comment: By mean score, do you mean `df.topics.str.split(',',expand=True).astype(int).mean(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unnest then `groupby` and `agg`

```
df.topics=df.topics.str.split(',')
New_df=pd.DataFrame({'topics':np.concatenate(df.topics.values),'id':df.id.repeat(df.topics.apply(len)),'score':df.score.repeat(df.topics.apply(len))})

New_df.groupby('topics').score.agg(['count','mean'])

Out[1256]: 
        count  mean
topics             
1           2   5.0
11          2   8.0
12          1   6.0
18          2   5.5
22          1   9.0
30          4   6.5
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately with my real data I get an error on `'topics': np.concatenate(df.topics.values)` - the error is `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`. I think this is because the split arrays are of variable length - how to deal with?

Comment: @Richard did you assign it back after split?

Comment: It was because I had some `NaN` values in my data - replacing those fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard aha , np.nan will cause the problem , you can replace the nan :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [111]: def mean1(x): return np.array(x).astype(int).mean()

In [112]: df.topics.str.split(',', expand=False).agg([mean1, len])
Out[112]:
       mean1  len
0  21.000000       3
1  19.666667       3
2  14.333333       3
3  16.333333       3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. Reindex & stack, then groupby & agg.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
  { 'id': 1, 'score': 9, 'topics': '11,22,30' },
  { 'id': 2, 'score': 7, 'topics': '11,18,30' },
  { 'id': 3, 'score': 6, 'topics': '1,12,30' },
  { 'id': 4, 'score': 4, 'topics': '1,18,30' }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.topics = df.topics.str.split(',')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.topics.tolist(), index=[df.id, df.score])\
                   .stack()\
                   .reset_index(name='topics')\
                   .drop('level_2', 1)

df2.groupby('topics').score.agg(['count', 'mean']).reset_index()
```

Comment: All in one line. `(df.set_index(['id','score']).topics.str.split(',', expand=True)
  .stack().reset_index(name='Topic')
  .groupby('Topic').agg({'id':'size','score':'mean'}))`

Comment: @ScottBoston That might work too. More than one way!